# How to design a database to achieve navigation effect in a website with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

So I'm trying to build a website in which I will have different Youtube videos organized in playlists.I want a page to display the playlists I have grouped by categories, and a watch page to watch the videos with "previous" and "next" buttons. I am using PHP and MySql. I always sucked at databases and table relationships; so I'm clueless about this. So my questions are:

first of all, What would be the best way to organized my videos? I want my links to be something like watch.php?playlist=`n`&video=`n`, where video=1 will always be the first video on the corresponding playlist. Right now I have a `playlist` table with the columns `playlist_id(PK)` `playlist_name` and `category`. Then I have a table for each specific playlist, the columns for these are: `video_id(PK)` `playlist id(FK ref playlist.playlist_id)` `video_name` and `url`. Am I on the right direction there?

my second question is: is it a good idea to store the Youtube video urls in the database? if not, what's the best way to do it?

and last but not least, what is the best way to accomplish the navigation effect I want(linking to the previous and next videos from the currently displayed one)? I know I have to use the _GET and _POST methods for this and I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out but if you know a very good way to explain this I will appreciate it

Comment: When you say "Navigation Effect", Do you mean transitions?

Comment: Asking for a full design suggestion is a bit much. We're here to help each other understand various smaller problems and then we use our reasoning and previous experience to build stuff.

Comment: Try looking at the design/structure of open source platforms and find the most common approaches and decide if they fit your needs, adapt & improve them and when a particular problem arises we can make it work.

Comment: Otherwise we're here with our knowledge, you're there with your requirements and you're trickling information based on what people are asking you. In designing/structuring the big picture is more important than the smaller details so you really can't "design by wire".

Comment: In my opinion your table structure for this "simple" case should be fine. If you want to have any further information you could read:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Wow... 5 replies in a day... this site is the best! and when you put it that way @MihaiStancu, I guess you are right. But what about my second question? What's the best way to store youtube videos? right now I have the urls stored as strings.

Comment: And thank you a lot @puelo at least I don't feel so lost about this anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On your first question:

There are many useful database structure patterns you may want to look into.

### Adjacency list

One of the simplest and most intuitive is the adjacency list (1:M):

```
CREATE TABLE `playlist` (
    `playlist_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `youtube_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL; DEFAULT '',

    -- other necessary fields pertaining to a playlist

    PRIMARY KEY(`playlist_id`),
    KEY(`youtube_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `video` (
    `video_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `youtube_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL; DEFAULT '',

    -- other necessary fields pertaining to a video

    PRIMARY KEY(`video_id`),
    KEY(`youtube_id`)
);
```

The above only has the drawback of making it impossible to assign a video to multiple playlists -- unless you accept the fact that a video record can have different `video_id`s but the same `youtube_id` (you insert the same video twice into the table in order to associate it with 2 playlists).

### Junction table

Another classical database design pattern is the junction table (M:N) which implies creating a separate table which associates a `playlist_id` with a `video_id`. This allows you to insert a video only once in the video table and associate it to multiple playlists.

### Ancestor table

If you need to create hierarchies such as categories of playlists which have subcategories which finally have playlists you can use the ancestor table (similar to a junction table) by storing each level of relation "parent/grandparent/ancestor-level-n".

### Taxonomies:

Another approach is the taxonomy pattern in which you can construct various types of taxonomies. For example if you want to organize your playlists as categories which contain subcategories which contain playlists (to which videos are attached).

You may want to create a single `taxonomy` table to store in it either category records or playlist records.

## On your second question:

Storing YouTube videos URLs in the DB is perfectly fine. Many CMS platforms keep links and/or entire embed snippets as `varchar` or `text` in the database.

Since you know you only want YouTube videos you can take advantage of that and store less data in your database by extracting only the relevant content from the YouTube URL.

URL: www.youtube.com/watch?v=**VIDEOID**&list=**LISTID**

You can [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.parse-url.php) to get the query string and then [parse_query](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.parse-str.php) to get the `v` and `list` parameters respectively.

If the above advice is good for your usecase (you're sure youtube is and will always be your most important/only provider) you can drop the `playlist_id` and the `video_id` and use the `youtube_id` from each table as the primary key (they're short enough, you can index them well, you can set a unique constraint on them etc.).